# Change all files while moving a bunch of files

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Any suggestions on how I should approach this please?
I need to move all files in a directory and change their names removing everything before and including the first '_' eg:

Example Before:

```
data directory
DT21_Filename1
D22_Filename2
D33_Filename3
```

export_data directory
Example After:

```
Filename1
Filename2
Filename3
```

Comment: There are many questions on Stack Overflow dealing with bulk renaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rename all the file with:

```
rename 's/([^_]*_)//' *
```

Then move them to the directory as:

```
mv * PATH_TO_NEW_DIRECTORY
```

You can also write a script for the above.

Script:

```
curr_dir=$PWD
cd $1
for i in *; do
    rename 's/([^_]*_)//' $i
done;
mv * "$curr_dir/$2"
```

Usage:

```
bash filename.sh path_to_old_directory relative_path_to_new_directory_from current
```

This will rename and move files from old_directory to new_directory.

If you are giving absolute path for new directory:

```
cd $1
for i in *; do
    rename 's/([^_]*_)//' $i
done;
mv * $2
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. However, how do I point to a directory to do that within a bash script please?

Answer (score 1):

```
cd SOURCE_DIR
for file in *; do
    newname=`echo $file | sed 's/[^_]*_//'`
    mv $file DESTINATION_DIR/$newname
done
```